# about php... how to convert string to array then show out?

Tags: php

i have this string -

```
$result = "ABCDE";
```

and i want to seperate them to 3 parts

```
(like part 1 = A, part 2 = B, part 3 = C..., part 5 = E)
```

,give a name to each of them

```
part 1(A) = Apple
part 2(B) = Orange
part 3(C) = Ice-cream
part 3(D) = Water
part 5(E) = Cow
```

then the finally output is like

Output : You choose Apple, Orange, Ice-cream, Water, Cow

or like this

```
$result = "ACE";
```

Output : You choose Apple, Ice-cream, Cow

i have tried using array

```
$result = "ABCDE";
$showing = array(A => 'Apple , ', B => 'Orange , ', C => 'Ice-cream , ',
 D => 'Water , ', E => 'Cow , ');
echo  $showing[$result];
```

but i got nothing while output, seems array is not working in fixed string.

i want to know how to do it

Comment: You have no key called `ABCDE` set in the `$showing` array, so it doesn't show anything. You'll want to take the `$result` string apart into individual characters and output all the array elements that intersect with this array (hint hint *cough* `array_intersect` *cough*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one line magic:

```
echo implode('',array_intersect_key($showing,array_flip(str_split($result))));
```

Comment: codaddict & Vikk both of you are correct, great job! Just wonder i can  have two accepted answer, those two codes are really great and for this time i pick Vikk.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function [str_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) to split the string into individual letters, which can later be used as keys of your associative array.

Also you don't need to add comma at the end of each string. Instead you can use the `implode` function to join your values:

```
$input = "ABCDE";
$showing = array('A' => 'Apple', 'B' => 'Orange', 'C' => 'Ice-cream',
                 'D' => 'Water', 'E' => 'Cow');
$key_arr = str_split($input);
$val_arr = array();
foreach($key_arr as $key) {
        $val_arr[] = $showing[$key];
}

echo "You choose ".implode(',',$val_arr)."\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access characters from a string similar to elements in an array, like this:

```
$string = "ABCDE";
echo $string[2];    // "C"
```

Technically, it's not *really* treating it like an array, it just uses a similar syntax.

You could use

```
$choices= array('A' => 'Apple', 'B' => 'Orange', 'C' => 'Ice-cream',
  'D' => 'Water', 'E' => 'Cow');
$selected[] = array();

for ($i = 0, $len = strlen($result); $i < $len; $i++) {
  $selected[] = $choices[$string[$i]];
}

echo "You have selected: " . implode(', ', $selected);
```

Although str_split, as others have suggested, would also work.